# Launch Bootstrap 4v6 Modal on page load?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to develop a subscription pop up modal box using the latest framework from Bootstrap 4. However, I do not want my clients to click the button to subscribe, I want the subscription box to pop up as soon the page load. After numerous of tutorials, each one has failed. Does anyone know how to get around this?

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
```

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
 });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modal is missing a closing `</div>`. Also make sure you're including `jquery` before `bootstrap.js`.

https://www.codeply.com/go/gMtlZbdyHi

Comment: I tried putting it in my editor and it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the elements are not loaded when the function is called.
Try to use it in a timeout like

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 5000)
```

If it is working -> Find a better solution to figure out if components already loaded

If not working -> Does the console say something? Try to debug and have a look if  $('myModal') is in deed returning the element and if ".modal" is defined.

Comment: Console checks out fine, I do not know what could be the problem. This is very frustrating. I just want a simple popup modal on a pageload, where that can display subscription information